# Clion doesnt recognize header files

Tags: c++, windows, header-files, libraries, clion

I want to program in C++ in Clion with Windows 10.

When I include header files like `#include <iostream>` or `#include "string"`, it tells me "iostream" file was not found.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] and show your code instead of describing it. You probbaly want `#include <string>` and `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky `#include "string"` should also search the library part, after the local lookup.

Comment: I added a photo of the error